# Send Outlook Messenger to System Tray in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, notification-area

How to send the Outlook Messenger to system tray of Microsoft Windows 7 when its is minimized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, use [Tray It!](http://www.teamcti.com/trayit/trayit.htm) (free) or [Actual Window Minimizer](http://www.actualtools.com/windowminimizer/) (not free). It'll work with Outlook LAN Messenger too...

Answer (score 0):

Although I am using Outlook 2007 but I think this option was available in 2007 already:

- Right-click the tray-icon of Outlook
- Select `Hide When Minimized`

This will hide the Outlook taskband entry when Outlook is minimized.

Edit: Just discovered that indeed Outlook 2007 seems not to have this option. Instead you would have to use a tool called "HideOutlook" or similar. See [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/hide-outlook-2010-in-windows-7-taskbar-system-tray/) for example.

Edit: I just noticed now that the question was rather about Outlook Messenger ([Outlook LAN Messenger](http://www.outlookmessenger.com/OM/)?) which seems to be some 3rd party software. Of course it does not have to follow the same guidelines as Microsoft Outlook itself.

Although there is a very generic tool called [RBTray](http://moitah.net/). Once startet it allows you to simply right-click any minimize button to send the application to tray. There are a couple of other "minimize-to-tray" applications out there but RBTray is very small, simple and I personally like the "right click minimize" feature.

Comment: Will it work for Outlook Messenger (not for Outlook)

Comment: Not sure about Outlook Messenger. But have a look at my update. You might give RBTray a try.